# XSD Schema - unable to add annotation in simple type

Tags: xsd, schema

I have a problem with schema and **annotation** for **simpleType**.

My schema:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

/...CODE.../

  <xsd:simpleType name="DateTimeType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:dateTime"/>
    <xsd:annotation> <!--Line: 161 -->
        <xsd:documentation>
            Date time
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
  </xsd:simpleType>

</xsd:schema>
```

My error

```
lineNumber: 161; columnNumber: 25; s4s-elt-must-match.1: The content 
of 'simpleType' must match (annotation?, (restriction | list | union)). 
A problem was found starting at: annotation.
```

How can I fix it ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I fixed it. What is important: the order of elements in exaple simple type. So, good order is annotation, and then e.q. restriction or union.

```
<xsd:simpleType name="DateTimeType">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>
            Date time
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:dateTime"/>
</xsd:simpleType>
```